# How to prevent Display view in Eclipse Debug perspective from going away quickly on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

On Mac, in Debug perspective, in Java editor, when I select an expression, for example `i < 5` to display the value of the selected expression, the Display pop-up window is supposed to appear and stay. Instead, most of the time it appears and then goes away quickly.